# Need help parsing a piece of HTML

Tags: python, html

I am trying to parse the date from the following HTML

`i = <|td class="text_view_data" scope="row">06/07/19<|/td|>`

```
When using beautifulsoup i.td returns "none"
```

I want to capture "06/07/19" but am unsure how to do so

Comment: Have a look at Beautiful Soup. This helps to parse html

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions are awesome. I highly recommend using regexr.com for practicing and learning!

In python, what you'll have to do is something like this ([Here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)'s a good website for more reference/research):

```
import re

date_regex = re.compile(r'\d\d/\d\d/\d\d')
date_match = re.search(date_regex, html)
date = date_match.group(0)
```